# How to use or predicate in less guards

Tags: css, less

I have tried to compile some less files which have the guard with or predicates. I know there is an and predicate for less guards, is ther any code to gave or predicate to my guards?

Please refer the less codes as below

```
@tree: "";
& when (@tree = "Neem"), (@tree = ""){
/*------Neem-------*/
 .neem{
   color: green;
 }
}
& when (@tree = "Other"), (@tree = ""){
/*------Others-------*/
 .others{
    color: brown;
  }
}
```

So I can access all the codes or such specific code to pass some variable in the less css.

The above code is working fine in less.js compilation but it doesn't work in the dotless compilation.

Please let me know if I have missed something? I got this error while compiling in dotless version 1.5.1.0. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: `,` is the correct operator and your code would work with the official Less compiler if you add the rules within a selector block. I am not sure if dotLess is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I have the updated dotLess but it throws the error :-(

Comment: I didn't mean your version but the latest compiler version used by dotLess itself could be outdated and is probably not supporting the operator. From a pure Less perspective, your code is pretty fine.

Comment: The problem is the comment line, when I remove the comments inside the  rules its gone. But I got another issue "Unable to cast object of type 'dotless.Core.Parser.Tree.Ruleset' to type 'dotless.Core.Parser.Tree.Rule' " :-(